# How to addClass and removeClass using jQuery on hidden elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html code:

```
<div class="Image" style="display: block;">1</div>
<div class="Image" style="display: none;">2</div>
<div class="Image" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div class="Image" style="display: none;">4</div>
```

The display: block property will run from lines 1 through 4 using a other javascript code.

I want to addClass "slide-in" to the line with display: block property and addClass "slide-out" to line with display: none property.

And this is what i want:

```
<div class="Image slide-in" style="display: block;">1</div>
<div class="Image slide-out" style="display: none;">2</div>
<div class="Image slide-out" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div class="Image slide-out" style="display: none;">4</div>
```

Is there any way to do that. Please help me, thank you everyone!

Comment: My problem is the selector with the style property.

Comment: please explain your problem clearly. What you wanna make

Comment: I revised the post to make it clearer what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. We need to use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function of jQuery to get all the elements with class `.Image` and the check for styles and if its `block` then we `addClass` the class `slide-in` OR else we add class `slide-out`

In order to check for current styles - We can simply use [.css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method of `jQuery` to get the current `style` of the `elements`.

Also, to add classes to the `hidden` element we need `virtually` show them in the `DOM` using block **>** apply class slide-out **>** hide them again.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('.Image').each(function(i, el) {
  if ($(el).css("display") == 'block') {
    $(el).addClass('slide-in') //add Class slide-in
  } else {
    $(el).css("display", "block") //show them virtually
    $(el).addClass('slide-out') //apply class slide-out
    $(el).css("display", "none") //hide them again
  }
  console.log(el) //classes added
})
```

```css
.slide-in {
  background: green;
}

.slide-out {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Image" style="display: block;">1</div>
<div class="Image" style="display: none;">2</div>
<div class="Image" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div class="Image" style="display: none;">4</div>
```